# My USB printer works fine on my computer, but is constantly offline in local network

Tags: networking, windows-10, printing, printer, network-printer

My printer is HP LaserJet Pro M12a. Every computer runs on Windows 10.

Apparently the printer used to work on the local network before I started working at my company, now it doesn't. What I gathered is that the Windows 10 1803 update broke Homegroup, and that it could be the culprit. I followed [this guide](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/homegroup-removed-how-to-get-network-sharing-work/01277332-2916-4a68-853a-116696b20743) and enabled services as it told.

When I navigate to \localhost in explorer I see my printer. However, I can not connect to it or do anything meaningful. Instead an error appears (code 0x00000709) telling me to check the printer name or see if it's connected to the network.

I'm out of ideas. I followed everything I googled, I reinstalled the printer already (deleted printer and reinstalled driver), switched USB ports. I can ping to the computer connected to the printer. It's IP used to be DHCP, but I changed it to be static.

**Update**:
When I follow [this solution](https://www.infopackets.com/news/10347/how-fix-hp-laserjet-1200-wont-recognize-windows-10) I can't run Dot4x64 driver. It instantly exits. Logging through command line just says the MSI installer installed successfully, however it is not the case, as the next step wants me to select Dot4 printer port - it is not there.
I also attempted to unpack the installer with 7zip, although that did not help, as it is a driver and I have no clue how would I go about installing it manually.
If anyone could help with this I'd be grateful, this solution does seem promising and I would like to try it - it's just that the .msi installer doesn't cooperate...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [this driver](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-LaserJet-Pro-M11-M13-Printer-series/9365405/model/9365407)?

You could also use
[this solution](https://www.infopackets.com/news/10347/how-fix-hp-laserjet-1200-wont-recognize-windows-10),
involving installing the 
[HP Laserjet USB (DOT4) communication driver](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/COL44939/fp-148007-1/Dot4x64.msi)
followed by
[HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PostScript (64-bit)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-universal-print-driver-series-for-windows/503548/model/4157320).

You could also try running Microsoft’s
[Automated Printer Troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=260616).

If nothing works with the latest Windows 10 version, you could perhaps install
it inside a virtual machine with an earlier version of Windows.

Comment: Whenever I try to install Dot4x64 driver, the installer exits with no error. I tried to get a log through command line and it claims the installer ran successfully, but it really did not. No files were extracted, and I can't do the rest of the solution (can't find dot4 printer port)

Comment: I added more to my answer.

Comment: There are no .cab files. If I try to install .inf files it just says it (paraphrasing) "couldn't find specified file". If you meant I should unpack .cat files, they're not possible to view in 7zip.

Comment: Right. The DOT4 driver is only the input for the other one. I'll be looking into this later on for more exact instructions.

Comment: Finally I don't understand the problem. It seems straight forward: Run `Dot4x64.msi`, then run `upd-ps-x64-6.7.0.23989.exe` and let it install. When it arrives to the "Add Printer" page, choose your option which is perhaps "Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname".

Comment: I tried to install Dot4x64.msi on two different computers with same effect. Maybe there's something wrong with my company machines, because I used to have similar issue with a driver for a different printer. Unpacking the installer worked in that case, but here it does not.

Comment: In order to write my above comment, I tried it on a Windows 10 VM and reached the "Add Printer" page without problem. Perhaps it's the anti-virus, so see if you can disable it temporarily.

Comment: It does not appear to be a problem with my antivirus. I disabled it and tried installing the driver again, it did not work. I use Kaspersky if it's of any relevance.

Comment: Sorry, that's as far as I can go. I don't know why this doesn't work on your company's computers.